# Using rollapply and lm over multiple columns of data

Tags: r, zoo, lm, rollapply

I have a data frame similar to the following with a total of 500 columns:

```
Probes <- data.frame(Days=seq(0.01, 4.91, 0.01), B1=5:495,B2=-100:390, B3=10:500,B4=-200:290)
```

I would like to calculate a rolling window linear regression where my window size is 12 data points and each sequential regression is separated by 6 data points. For each regression, "Days" will always be the x component of the model, and the y's would be each of the other columns (B1, followed by B2, B3, etc).  I would then like to save the co-efficients as a dataframe with the existing column titles (B1, B2, etc).

I think my code is close, but is not quite working.  I used rollapply from the zoo library.

```
slopedata<-rollapply(zoo(Probes), width=12, function(Probes) { 
 coef(lm(formula=y~Probes$Days, data = Probes))[2]
 }, by = 6, by.column=TRUE, align="right")
```

If possible, I would also like to have the "xmins" saved to a vector to add to the dataframe. This would mean the smallest x value used in each regression (basically it would be every 6 numbers in the "Days" column.)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: if i am understanding your question correctly, you are going to need to "loop" in two directions. The `rollapply` from `zoo` will give you the window direction (moving down your rows). But if you are going to have multiple `y` regressions, you're also going to need to loop through each of those possibilities (each column being another regression)

Comment: Ok thanks.  Are you saying I'll need to loop it in addition to the rollapply function?  I'm not quite sure how this would look when put all together.

Comment: Also do you think the colwise function from plyr would work for this?

Comment: this depends on what it is exactly that you want. do you want to have a regression y1 vs x, y2 vs x, y3 vs x,...etc. by themselves. or in addition to the rolling window y1 vs. x (only first 12 i.e., 1-12), y1 vs. x (only 18-30),...,etc

Comment: I would want the second....the regression by column in addition to a rolling window. Almost what you wrote except that the rolling window would move every 6 cells, like this: Y1[1:12]~x,  Y1[6:18]~x, Y1[12:24], etc, etc.  So I would basically end up with a matrix with 1/6th of the values I originally had.  Will make an example matrix for this so that it’s clear.

Comment: yeah sorry, that is what i thought you wanted. i just wanted to be sure. I also messed up the indices. But i believe my answer addresses that. Let me know below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Define a zoo object `z` whose data contains `Probes` and whose index is taken from the first column of Probes, i.e. `Days`.  Noting that `lm` allows `y` to be a matrix define a `coefs` function which computes the regression coefficients.  Finally `rollapply` over `z`.  Note that the index of the returned object gives xmin.

```
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(Probes, Probes[[1]])

coefs <- function(z) c(unlist(as.data.frame(coef(lm(z[,-1] ~ z[,1])))))
rz <- rollapply(z, 12, by = 6, coefs, by.column = FALSE, align = "left")
```

giving:

```
> head(rz)
     B11 B12  B21 B22 B31 B32  B41 B42
0.01   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
0.07   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
0.13   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
0.19   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
0.25   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
0.31   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
```

Note that `DF <- fortify.zoo(rz)` could be used if you needed a data frame representation of `rz`.

**2)** An alternative somewhat similar approch would be to `rollaplly` over the row numbers:

```
library(zoo)
y <- as.matrix(Probes[-1])
Days <- Probes$Days
n <- nrow(Probes)
coefs <- function(ix) c(unlist(as.data.frame(coef(lm(y ~ Days, subset = ix)))), 
      xmins = Days[ix][1])
r <- rollapply(1:n, 12, by = 6, coefs)
```

Comment: Note that this has been revised to be shorter.

Comment: Thanks, this code also works and the values match what I get after testing a few in Excel.  I don't need the intercepts in my dataframe so I'm guessing I would just add a [-1] somewhere in the coef function if I want to eliminate these columns?

Comment: In that case the `coefs` function can be simplified to: `coefs <- function(z) coef(lm(z[,-1] ~ z[,1]))[2,]` in (1).

Comment: @user507 i was wondering if you could run both codes and see which one is more efficient

Comment: Out of the two above similar codes, the second (rollapply over row numbers) is the better of the two for my purposes and is the one I ended up using.  The below code worked, but I wasn't able to work out the kink with the values being slightly off.  As you suggested, I also originally thought it could be an indexing issue, but trying multiple different indexing changes didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# here are the xmin values you wanted
xmins <- Probes$Days[seq(1,nrow(Probes),6)]

# here we build a function that will run regressions across the columns
# y1 vs x, y2 vs x, y3 vs x...
# you enter the window and by (12/6) in order to limit the interval being
# regressed. this is later called in do.call
runreg <- function(Probes,m,window=12,by=6){

  # beg,end are used to specify the interval
  beg <- seq(1,nrow(Probes),by)[m]
  end <- beg+window-1

  # this is used to go through all the columns
  N <- ncol(Probes)-1
  tmp <- numeric(N)
  # go through each column and store the coefficients in tmp
  for(i in 1:N){
     y <- Probes[[i+1]][beg:end]
     x <- Probes$Days[beg:end]
     tmp[i] <- coef(lm(y~x))[2][[1]]
  }
  # put all our column regressions into a dataframe
  res <- rbind('coeff'=tmp)
  colnames(res) <- colnames(Probes)[-1]

  return(res)
}

# now that we've built the function to do the column regressions
# we just need to go through all the window-ed regressions (row regressions)
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(xmins),function(m) runreg(Probes,m)))

# these rownames are the index of the xmin values
rownames(res) <- seq(1,nrow(Probes),6)
res <- data.frame(res,xmins)
```

Comment: Yes this worked well.  The values I get when double-checking a few of the slopes in Excel are slightly different, but I'm guessing this is probably due to differences in how the two different programs fit the linear model rather than to issues with coding.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: that may also be an issue with the indexing. Maybe I am one unit off? But that's an easy fix. The general structure should help!

try changing `end <- beg+window-1` that will make it correct I believe. the index will now become:

1:(1+12-1) instead of the previous 1:(1+12)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `rollRegres` package as follows

```r
# setup data
Probes <- data.frame(
  # I changed the days to be intergers
  Days=seq(1L, 491L, 1L),
  B1=5:495, B2=-100:390, B3=10:500 , B4=-200:290)

# setup grp argument
grp_arg <- as.integer((Probes$Days - 1L) %/% 6)

# estimate coefs. width argument is realtive in grp units
library(rollRegres)
X <- cbind(1, Probes$Days / 100)
Ys <- as.matrix(Probes[, 2:5])
out <- lapply(1:ncol(Ys), function(i)
  roll_regres.fit(x = X, y = Ys[, i], width = 2L, grp = grp_arg)$coefs)
out <- do.call(cbind, out)

# only keep the complete.cases and the unique values
colnames(out) <- sapply(1:4, function(i) paste0("B", i, 0:1))
out <- out[c(T, grp_arg[-1] != head(grp_arg, -1)), ]
out <- out[complete.cases(out), ]
head(out)
#R      B10 B11  B20 B21 B30 B31  B40 B41
#R [1,]   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
#R [2,]   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
#R [3,]   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
#R [4,]   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
#R [5,]   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
#R [6,]   4 100 -101 100   9 100 -201 100
```

The solution is a lot faster than e.g., the `zoo` solution

```r
library(zoo) coefs <- function(z) c(unlist(as.data.frame(coef(lm(z[,-1] ~ z[,1]))))) microbenchmark::microbenchmark(   rollapply = {
    z <- zoo(Probes, Probes[[1]])
    rz <- rollapply(z, 12, by = 6, coefs, by.column = FALSE, align = "left")   },   roll_regres = {
    grp_arg <- as.integer((Probes$Days - 1L) %/% 6)

    X <- cbind(1, Probes$Days / 100)
    Ys <- as.matrix(Probes[, 2:5])
    out <- lapply(1:ncol(Ys), function(i)
      roll_regres.fit(x = X, y = Ys[, i], width = 2L, grp = grp_arg)$coefs)
    out <- do.call(cbind, out)

    colnames(out) <- sapply(1:4, function(i) paste0("B", i, 0:1))
    out <- out[c(T, grp_arg[-1] != head(grp_arg, -1)), ]
    out <- out[complete.cases(out), ]
    head(out)   } )
#R Unit: microseconds
#R        expr       min        lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
#R   rollapply 53392.614 56330.492 59793.106 58363.2825 60902.938 119206.76   100
#R roll_regres   865.186   920.297  1074.161   983.9015  1047.705   5071.41   100
```

At present you though need to install the package from Github due to an error in the validation in version `0.1.0`. Thus, run

```
devtools::install_github("boennecd/rollRegres", upgrade_dependencies = FALSE,
                         build_vignettes = TRUE)
```