# rolling regression by group in the tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, broom, rolling-computation

There are many questions about rolling regression in R, but here I am specifically looking for something that uses `dplyr`, `broom` and (if needed) `purrr`.

This is what makes this question different. I want to be `tidyverse` consistent. Is is possible to do a proper running regression with tidy tools such as `purrr:map` and `dplyr`?

Please consider this simple example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

mydata = data_frame('group' = c('a','a', 'a','a','b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
                     'y' = c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5),
                     'x' = c(2,4,6,8,6,9,12,15),
                     'date' = c(ymd('2016-06-01', '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03', '2016-06-04',
                                    '2016-06-03', '2016-06-04', '2016-06-05','2016-06-06')))

  group     y     x date      
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1 a      1.00  2.00 2016-06-01
2 a      2.00  4.00 2016-06-02
3 a      3.00  6.00 2016-06-03
4 a      4.00  8.00 2016-06-04
5 b      2.00  6.00 2016-06-03
6 b      3.00  9.00 2016-06-04
7 b      4.00 12.0  2016-06-05
8 b      5.00 15.0  2016-06-06
```

For each group (in this example, `a` or `b`):

1. compute the *rolling* regression of `y` on `x` *over the last 2 observations*.
2. store the coefficient of that rolling regression in a column of the dataframe.

Of course, as you can see, the rolling regression can only be computed for the last 2 rows in each group.

I have tried to use the following, but without success.

```
data %>% group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(rolling_coef = do(tidy(rollapply(. ,
                    width=2, 
                    FUN = function(df) {t = lm(formula=y ~ x, 
                                              data = as.data.frame(df), 
                                              na.rm=TRUE); 
                    return(t$coef) },
                    by.column=FALSE, align="right"))))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: subscript out of bounds.
In addition: There were 21 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Any ideas?

Expected output for the last two rows of the first `a` group is 0.5 and 0.5 (there is indeed a perfect linear correlation between `y` and `x` in this example)

More specifically:

```
mydata_1 <- mydata %>% filter(group == 'a',
                  row_number() %in% c(1,2))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group     y     x
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      1.00  2.00
2 a      2.00  4.00
> tidy(lm(y ~ x, mydata_1))['estimate'][2,]
[1] 0.5
```

and also

```
mydata_2 <- mydata %>% filter(group == 'a',
                              row_number() %in% c(2,3)) 
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group     y     x
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      2.00  4.00
2 a      3.00  6.00
> tidy(lm(y ~ x, mydata_2))['estimate'][2,]
[1] 0.5
```

**EDIT:**

interesting follow-up to this question here [rolling regression with confidence interval (tidyverse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753158/rolling-regression-with-confidence-interval-tidyverse?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using rollapply and lm over multiple columns of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813627/using-rollapply-and-lm-over-multiple-columns-of-data)

Comment: no duplicate at all. I know that SO question. What I am looking for is a `purrr`, tidyverse solution which is not available on the link you provide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define a function `Coef` whose argument is formed from `cbind(y, x)` and which regresses y on x with an intercept, returning the coefficients.  Then apply `rollapplyr` using the current and prior rows over each group.  If by *last* you meant the 2 prior rows to the current row, i.e. exclude the current row, then replace 2 with `list(-seq(2))` as an argument to `rollapplyr`.

```
Coef <- . %>% as.data.frame %>% lm %>% coef

mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(cbind(reg_col = select(., y, x) %>% rollapplyr(2, Coef, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA),
           date_col = select(., date))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  group `reg_col.(Intercept)` reg_col.x date      
  <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl> <date>    
1 a      NA                      NA     2016-06-01
2 a       0                       0.500 2016-06-02
3 a       0                       0.500 2016-06-03
4 a       0                       0.500 2016-06-04
5 b      NA                      NA     2016-06-03
6 b       0.00000000000000126     0.333 2016-06-04
7 b     - 0.00000000000000251     0.333 2016-06-05
8 b       0                       0.333 2016-06-06
```

### Variation

A variation of the above would be:

```
mydata %>% 
       group_by(group) %>% 
       do(select(., date, y, x) %>% 
          read.zoo %>% 
          rollapplyr(2, Coef, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA) %>%
          fortify.zoo(names = "date")
       ) %>% 
       ungroup
```

### Slope Only

If only the slope is needed there are further simplifications possible.  We use the fact that the slope equals `cov(x, y) / var(x)`.

```
slope <- . %>% { cov(.[, 2], .[, 1]) / var(.[, 2])}
mydata %>%
       group_by(group) %>%
       mutate(slope = rollapplyr(cbind(y, x), 2, slope, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)) %>%
       ungroup
```

Comment: really cool but I am puzzled by the crazy small coefficients here? Also, is it possible to have a proper column naming?

Comment: The small coefficients are basically 0 and result from floating point approximations -- nothing to do with rollapply or dplyr. I updated the code and output a few times and the names should be ok now.

Comment: Thanks Grothendieck. I now realize there is some important missing piece here (my fault). As is, the code does not allow me to merge back the regression results to the original dataset because the row index information is lost (we only select(y,x) in your code. I have updated the example dataframe in my question. Do you see an easy way to update your nice answer so that both the group AND the date appear in the output dataframe? That way we can merge back if needed. thanks!!

Comment: I tried this, but I wonder if the data will always be correctly aligned here ```mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(cbind(reg_col = select(., y, x) %>% rollapply(2, Coef, by.column = FALSE, align = 'right', fill = NA),
     date_col = select(., date))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Yes, the data will be aligned if you use `fill=NA`.  That fills in the otherwise missing rows with NA values.  (Also suggest using `rollapplyr` with an r at the end as in my answer instead of `align = "right"`to keep code shorter.)

Comment: crazy stuff  I wonder which one is faster and more memory efficient with a large dataset

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an idea than an answer but maybe instead of using `group_by` try using `map` and your list of groups:

```
FUN <- function(g, df = NULL) {
  tmp <- tidy(rollapply(
    zoo(filter(df, group == g)),
    width = 2,
    FUN = function(z) {
      t <- lm(y ~ x, data = as.data.frame(z)) ; return(t$coef)
    },
    by.column = FALSE,
    align = "right"
    ))
  tmp$series <- c(rep('intercept', nrow(tmp) / 2), rep('slope', nrow(tmp) / 2))
  spread(tmp, series, value) %>% mutate(group = g)
}

map_dfr(list('a', 'b'), FUN, df = data)
```

Comment: that is interesting. can you please try to make it work in that context?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I added a few extra lines to return a cleaner result.  I'm honestly not familiar with `zoo`.  The results seem odd.  Shouldn't the slopes be 0.5 and 0.33?

Comment: please have a look at the updated question. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you're after?

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(data.frame(., rolling_coef = c(NA, rollapply(data = ., width = 2, FUN = function(df_) {
    d = data.frame(df_)
    d[, 2:3] <- apply(d[,2:3], MARGIN = 2, FUN = as.numeric)
    mod = lm(y ~ x, data = d)
    return(coef(mod)[2])
  }, by.column = FALSE, align = "right"))))
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
  group     y     x rolling_coef
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1 a        1.    2.       NA    
2 a        2.    4.        0.500
3 a        3.    6.        0.500
4 a        4.    8.        0.500
5 b        2.    6.       NA    
6 b        3.    9.        0.333
7 b        4.   12.        0.333
8 b        5.   15.        0.333
```

**Edit:** Slightly modified code, but `data_frame` will not accept the `.` group placeholder as an argument- not sure how to fix that.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(data.frame(., rolling_coef = c(NA, rollapplyr(data = ., width = 2, FUN = function(df_) {
    mod = lm(y ~ x, data = .)
    return(coef(mod)[2])
  }, by.column = FALSE))))
```

**Edit 2:** Using `fill = NA` rather than using `c(NA, ...)` achieves the same result.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  do(data.frame(., rolling_coef = rollapplyr(data = ., width = 2, FUN = function(df_) {
    mod = lm(y ~ x, data = .)
    return(coef(mod)[2])
  }, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)))
```

Comment: I just have a few questions.  what is the purpose of the `NA` here? why are you using `margin`? cant you use `dplyr::data_frame` and `purrr:map` instead of `data.frame` and `apply` in your code?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ - The `NA` is present because the first observation has no "previous 2" observations. I had assumed you wanted the regression to be on rows 1 and 2, then on 2 and 3, then on 3 and 4. But, there is no such regression for the first row since the regression is not performed for row 0 and 1. I can't figure out how to get `data_frame` to work, but actually the `apply` is unnecessary (I forgot to drop it from my first attempt). See edit.

Comment: ahh that's too bad... i dont think its safe to manually add this NA. I was hoping this could be automated. see Grothendieck s answer maybe? thanks anyway!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I really like Grothendieck's answer, it's slick and I think provides more easily flexible output! As far as I understand it, using `c(NA, ...)` is functionally the same as using `fill = NA` in any case where you are rolling from the first row- shown in edit 2 above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution similar to [G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49764546/5861244) but using the `rollRegres` package. I have to increase the `width` argument to 3 to avoid an error (by the way, why do you want a regression with so few observations?)

```r
library(rollRegres)
Coef <- . %>% { roll_regres.fit(x = cbind(1, .$x), y = .$y, width = 2L)$coefs }

mydata %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(cbind(reg_col = select(., y, x) %>% Coef,
           date_col = select(., date))) %>%
  ungroup
#R  Error in mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% do(cbind(reg_col = select(., y,  :
#R    Assertion on 'width' failed: All elements must be >= 3.

# change width to avoid error
Coef <- . %>% { roll_regres.fit(x = cbind(1, .$x), y = .$y, width = 3L)$coefs }
mydata %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(cbind(reg_col = select(., y, x) %>% Coef,
           date_col = select(., date))) %>%
    ungroup
#R # A tibble: 8 x 4
#R group  reg_col.1 reg_col.2 date
#R <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <date>
#R   1 a      NA           NA     2016-06-01
#R 2 a      NA           NA     2016-06-02
#R 3 a       1.54e-15     0.500 2016-06-03
#R 4 a      -5.13e-15     0.5   2016-06-04
#R 5 b      NA           NA     2016-06-03
#R 6 b      NA           NA     2016-06-04
#R 7 b      -3.08e-15     0.333 2016-06-05
#R 8 b      -4.62e-15     0.333 2016-06-06
#R Warning messages:
#R 1: In evalq((function (..., call. = TRUE, immediate. = FALSE, noBreaks. = FALSE,  :
#R    low sample size relative to number of parameters
#R 2: In evalq((function (..., call. = TRUE, immediate. = FALSE, noBreaks. = FALSE,  :
#R    low sample size relative to number of parameters
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to parallelize this? I got this to work for a dataframe with 68k observations but it's going to take an hour to run!

Comment: You can use the `parallel` package and particularly `clusterCall` and `clusterEvalQ` kinda like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31075231/5861244) to split the data sets into unique sets of `groups` on each process.

Comment: @philiporlando you can try new frollapply in data.table which is parallel, note that it's not yet in master, you need to install PR branch